Override Symfony / EasyAdmin default translation
How do I override or replace a default translation of a flash message in EasyAdmin?
I want to change the text that is shown when an entity is deleted for one Crud Controller but don't know how.
Writing a custom twig file seems excessive when I just want to replace a text.
I'm using easyadmin-bundle: 4.6


I could not overwrite the translation so i removed the delete action and added my own action in the crud controller:
public function configureActions(Actions $actions): Actions
{
    $actions = parent::configureActions($actions);
    $actions->remove(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, Action::DELETE);
    $actions->add(Crud::PAGE_INDEX, $this->archiveAction());
    return $actions;
}

private function archiveAction(): Action
{
    return Action::new('archive', 'action.archive')
        ->linkToCrudAction('archiveEntity')
        ->setHtmlAttributes([
            'onclick' => 'return confirm('Do you want to archive this item?']);
}


There is no official functionality to achieve this, however this Git issue will provide some insight into the process: https://github.com/EasyCorp/EasyAdminBundle/issues/3455#issuecomment-1517631289

Thanks, this looks promising but i was not able to get it to work. I'll update here if I make it work.

I could not get it to work and used a custom action. Thanks anyway!

@jaba, could you maybe share the custom action in an answer so others may benefit from it in the future?
